# Doubly Linked List - Head is changing without me changing it

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

The issue is with my findA method in DLinkedList class.
The method apparently changes my head.next to point to tmp.next
I created a list {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
I used

> findA(9)

and my list gets shrinked down to {9}, although functions gives correct result whether the given value is in my list or not (true or false)

On the other hand, my find method works perfectly and the only difference between the two is that I use Node tmp = head in findA
and Node tmp = head.next in find

Below is the complete code snippet. I realize some of the implementations are quite unprofessional. Any comments on that would be appreciated

```
public class Node <T extends Comparable<T>> {
T data;
Node prev;
Node next;

Node(){
}

Node(T val){
    data = val;
}  }

public class DLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
Node head;
Node tail;

DLinkedList(){
    head = new Node();    
    tail = new Node();
    tail.prev = head;
}

void insertInOrder(T value){
    Node insert = new Node(value);
    if(head.next==null){
        head.next = insert;
        insert.prev = head;
        insert.next = tail;
        tail.prev = insert;
    }
    else{
        insert.prev = tail.prev;
        tail.prev.next = insert;
        tail.prev = insert;
        insert.next = tail;
    }
}

boolean find (T value){
    boolean result = false;
    Node tmp = head.next;
    if (head!=null){
        while(tmp!=null){
            if(tmp.data.compareTo(value)!=0){
                tmp = tmp.next;
            }
            else{
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

 boolean findA (T value){
    boolean result = false;
    Node tmp = head;
    if (head!=null){
        while(tmp.next!=null){
            if(tmp.next.data.compareTo(value)!=0){
                tmp.next = tmp.next.next;
            }
            else{
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void deleteA(T value){
    Node tmp = head.next;

    while(tmp.data.compareTo(value)!=0){
            tmp = tmp.next;
    }
    if(tmp!=tail){
        if(tmp==head.next)
            head = tmp.next;
        else
             tmp.prev.next = tmp.next;

        if (tmp==tail)
            tail = tmp.prev;
        else
            tmp.next.prev = tmp.prev;
    }






}
void delete(T value){
    Node tmp = head.next;
    if(find(value)){
        while(tmp!=tail){
            if(tmp.data.compareTo(value)!=0){
                tmp = tmp.next;
            }
            else{
                tmp.prev.next = tmp.next;
                tmp.next.prev = tmp.prev;

                break;
            }
        }            
    }
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    Node tmp = head.next;
    String result = "";
        while(tmp!=tail){
            System.out.println(tmp.data);
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
    return result;
}  }

public class ListCheck {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DLinkedList list = new DLinkedList();
    DLinkedList listA = new DLinkedList();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        list.insertInOrder(i);
        listA.insertInOrder(i);
    }
    System.out.println(listA.findA(9));
    System.out.println(list.find(9));  
    listA.toString();
    System.out.println("");
    list.toString();
} }
```

Comment: Why are you changing `tmp.next` instead of `tmp`? Also who cares if head is null or `tmp` is `tail`. Just loop from head until it's null.

Comment: @CollinD because I initiated my tmp as head, and my head stores no data by design

Comment: Yes, and changing `tmp.next` will change `head.next` since `next` is a reference.

Answer (score 0):

In your findA, the way you move tmp is by doing

```
tmp.next = temp.next.next
```

in this way you are destroying the current pointer and rerouting it to the next node (java's shallow copy):

`tmp--->[node1]--->[node2]`   changes to  `tmp--->[node2]`

Therefore, at the end of the operation, your linkedlist only has the last node left.

Change it to `tmp = tmp.next` would help